# Ajax Request Being Ran an Extra Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am experiencing an issue in Javascript (jQuery) where my Ajax GET request is being ran an extra time. In fact, it is being ran even when I wrap it in an `if(false){ //AJAX REQUEST }`.

Why would it be ran an extra time, and why would it be ran even though it is in a false if statement?

**Extra Notes**

My actual scenario is that I am running a recursive function that makes a GET request for each iteration until a set stack is empty. In every test the function works wonders, but in the console of the browser I get a 404 when it tries to run the Ajax request an extra time with **null data**.

Example Screenshot: https://screencast.com/t/xRPK59Du6ZZ

**Psheudo Code**

```
function iterate(stack, success_function){

    if stack is empty
        success_function();
        return;

    //preserve original stack when popping
    new_stack = stack.slice(0);

    my_var = new_stack.pop();

    if (typeof my_var == "number"){

    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: "https://mywebsite/" + my_var + "?permanent_url=" + permanent_domain + "&access_all=true",
      success: function(data){
            work with data
            iterate(new_stack, success_function);
      }

    });

    }

}
```

Your help is appreciated. Thank you.

**Console error:** https://screencast.com/t/1wprZX7i8DzS

**UPDATE**

To put this into prospective, here is how my initial call is made:

```
function someFunction(){

    interate(initial_stack, function(){
        console.log('finished working with data');
    });

}
```

If I change this to be:

```
function someFunction(){

    console.log('about to process');
    interate(initial_stack, function(){
        console.log('finished working with data');
    });

}
```

"about to process" gets logged in the console a single time.

Comment: the problem with "psheudo" code is that you get "psheudo" answers

Comment: Maybe you're attaching an even handler twice?

Comment: I updated the code to be less pseudo. @ClaudioRedi I also confirmed that is not the case. The recursive function is be initialized once. 

Also, the key point here is that I can wrap this all in if(false){ //ajax request } and the ajax request still comes through and fails with the null url parameter.

Comment: **another update:** FIXED

Turns out another (remote) script on the page was making similar requests as I was and failing. While my code was working perfectly, this console error was coming from somewhere else.

/fp

Answer (score 0):

Another (remote) script on the page was making similar Ajax requests as me and failing. My own code was working fine, while the other script was causing the console error.

Nothing wrong here folks.